# Issues referencing labels in measuredfigure environment

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, threeparttable

As I want my captions to be the same width as my tables and figures I used the `threeparttable` package and the `measuredfigure` environment. However since, I have issues with referencing and labels of tables and figures in my text. Basically the figure/table number is replaced by ??. I've searched online but cannot find the appropriate help I need to fix this issue.

If I remove the caption and label from the `measuredfigure` environment and place it just above under `\centering` it works fine but the caption is no longer the width of the table/figure.

Many thanks

Egm1b

Here is WME

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,english,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
singlelinecheck = false}
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfloats in figure environment

\begin{document}

Below is summary table \Cref{tab:marker}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet6'
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{measuredfigure}
    \caption{Caribou age groups at Nunalleq based on epiphyseal fusion  \label{tab:marker}}
        \begin{tabular}{lcc}
            \toprule
            Age group & NISP  & \% NISP \\
            \midrule
            Adult (fused) & 441   & 88.6\% \\
            Subadult (unfused) & 46    & 9.2\% \\
            Juvenile (unfused) & 11    & 2.2\% \\
            \midrule
            Total & 498   & 100.0\% \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{measuredfigure}
\end{table}%
```

And MWE code for figures

```
Here is example with reference to \Cref{marker2}

\begin{figure} 
\centering 
\begin{measuredfigure} 
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{figures/ch7_caribouwear1} 
\caption{This is a very long caption very long} 
\label{marker2} 
\end{measuredfigure} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Why are you using the `measuredfigure` environment at all, and not the `threeparttable` environment?

Comment: Good point @Torbjørn T! I have replaced 'measuredfigure' with 'threeparttable'  and it works fine for tables. But I still have the issue with figures. Here is my MWE for figures that I should have added to my previous MWE: `Here is example with reference to \Cref{marker2} 
 
 \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{measuredfigure}
   \includegraphics[width=5cm]{figures/ch7_caribouwear1}
   \caption{This is a very long caption very long}
   \label{marker2}
  \end{measuredfigure}
 \end{figure}`

Comment: You can edit your question (there should be a link right above the comments), so perhaps you could add that code to the code in the question.

Comment: ok thanks I've just added the example code for figures. Hope that's clearer.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else is also still having trouble with this issue, I've figured out a workaround using phantomcaptions and resets of the figure counter. It may not be very elegant, but it seems to work, at least for me.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}% necessary for \phantomcaption

\usepackage[allfiguresdraft]{draftfigure}% dummy figures


\begin{document}


Below is an example with a reference to \Cref{fig:ex1}:

\begin{figure}[h] 
  \centering 
    \begin{measuredfigure} 
        \includegraphics[draft=false,width=5cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a very, very, very long caption.} 
    \end{measuredfigure} 
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
  \phantomcaption
  \label{fig:ex1} 
\end{figure}

And here is another example with a reference to \Cref{fig:ex2}:

\begin{figure}[h] 
  \centering 
    \begin{measuredfigure} 
        \includegraphics[draft=false,width=5cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This is another very, very, very long caption.} 
    \end{measuredfigure} 
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
  \phantomcaption
  \label{fig:ex2} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug to me, measuredfigure loose the label even in a simple document. But normally you know the width of the image and so you don't need the environment and can use a minipage:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{threeparttable,graphicx}
\begin{document}
Here is example with reference to \ref{fig:marker1} %missing

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{measuredfigure}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\caption{This is a very long caption very long\label{fig:marker1}}
\end{measuredfigure}
\end{figure}


Here is example with reference to \ref{fig:marker2}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{This is a very long caption very long\label{fig:marker2}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks MC Kosh, 
your workaround works perfectly.

Just on a side note, to make it more user friendly, I defined a function as follows in the beginning of my tex-file:

```
\newcommand*\MeasuredFigureLabel[1]{
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
    \phantomcaption
    \label{#1}
}
```

This makes this approach very workable.
This way everything stays clean looking, even if many figures must be included.
This is the adjusted include of the example figure:

```
\begin{figure}[h] 
  \centering 
    \begin{measuredfigure} 
        \includegraphics[draft=false,width=5cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is another very, very, very long caption.} 
    \end{measuredfigure} 
  \MeasuredFigureLabel{fig:ex1}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I solved it asking the figure length, and setting this length for text width. In my specific case, I wanted the "hang" and "justified" formats. The code was the following:

```
\usepackage[float]   %it isn't necessary for your purpose. If you don't want use, change "H" to "h" in \begin{figure}[H].
\newlength{\imgwidth}    %New variable \imgwidth
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=9 cm]{#1}    %9 cm is my setting. You can use another height / width, ...
    \settowidth{\imgwidth}{\includegraphics[height=9 cm]{#1}} %Put figure width equals to \imgwidth, remembering that's mandatory put the same height (9cm, in this case)
    \captionsetup{width=\imgwidth} %Put captionwidth equals to figure widt.
    \caption{blablabla}
    \label{blablabla}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to just drop `measuredfigure` and use `caption` package instead. Its `\captionbox` command ensures that the caption has the same width as the image.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \captionbox{\lipsum[23]\label{img}}%
       {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\end{figure}

Image reference: \ref{img}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Caption is perfectly within the image width]

It goes without saying that the main purpose of the `caption` package is actually to provide limitless possibilities for formatting captions, so you might find that it solved a lot of your other problems too. It's a widely popular, well maintained and well compatible package.

After that, it would make sense to just drop the (somewhat outdated) `threeparttable` package altogether and migrate to `tabularray`. Its `talltblr` table incorporates the `threeparttable` functionality rather nicely, along with a *cornucopia* of other features.